# Can I take the the bonus-action attack from Two-Weapon Fighting without taking the Attack action?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, actions, two-weapon-fighting

So I wanted to do a dual wielder rogue and I had a question about the bonus-action attack.

Can I take the bonus-action attack first and without taking an Attack action?

Basically, if I'm face to face with a big strong dude, can I take a bonus-action attack, and if that hits, do a Dodge action to help protect myself?

Or do I have to take the Attack action to do the bonus-action attack?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Are you talking about the bonus-action attack from the Two-Weapon Fighting rule?

Comment: Related: [Does two weapon fighting's qualifying “attack” have to be part of the “Attack” action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129913/does-two-weapon-fightings-qualifying-attack-have-to-be-part-of-the-attack-a), [Can you make a bonus-action attack from Two-Weapon Fighting before you take your action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131317/can-you-make-a-bonus-action-attack-from-two-weapon-fighting-before-you-take-your)

Comment: I've edited the post under the assumption that you meant "two-weapon fighting" instead of "two-handed fighting" in your title. Please check that my edits correctly interpret your question.

Answer (score 21):

## No, you cannot make an attack as a bonus action unless you also take the Attack action.

The text of the [Two-Weapon Fighting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TwoWeaponFighting) rule is pretty clear about this:

> **When you take the Attack action** and attack with a light melee weapon that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other hand.

i.e. the ability to make a melee attack as a bonus action is contingent upon you using your action to take the Attack action.

Comment: @András If you have an alternate answer, please use an answer post rather than starting a chat about it in comments on another answer.

Comment: @András The back-and-forth discussing the problems with adding it to this answer indicate that it’s not minor. That’s a good signal to either post it yourself with all the details worked out, or drop the tangent. Especially since it’s not even what the question was asking.